# Bot Framework - Teleram channel not published

Tags: botframework, telegram-bot

What do I need to do to make the Telegram channel publish?

Telegram not published
[image]

Access token added.

Answer (score 0):

The "publish" slider is there for listing your bot in the Bot Directory.  Microsoft has not yet opened the Bot Directory to 3rd party developers, so it remains disabled.  You can still create bots and share them with other people (in this case by providing them with the name of the telegram bot), you just can't list them in the directory as of yet.